# Attribute Error in snowflake.connector cursor() only when using MS VS Code but works fine in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a code that I want to turn from jupyter notebook into a script.
It's essentially pulling data from our Snowflake lake and doing some manipulations.
Here is what its like in Jupyter Notebook:

```py
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(<connection parameters>)         

ib_cursor = conn.cursor()
try: 
    ib_cursor.execute(ib_sql.read(), params)
    ib_rows = ib_cursor.fetchall()
```

This works in Jupyter code. The data loads into the `ib_rows` variable just fine.

In the MS Visual studio code script, I have simply created a class for my purposes.
Here is what it largely looks like:

```py
class snowflk_sql:
    def __init__(self, conn_parameters):
        self.connection_params = conn_parameters
        self.connection_obj  = snowflake.connector.connect(user= self.connection_params['user'],
                                        account= self.connection_params['account'],
                                        role= self.connection_params['role'],
                                        database= self.connection_params['database'],
                                        schema = self.connection_params['schema'],
                                        authenticator="externalbrowser",
                                        autocommit=True) 

    def sql_execute(self,parameter):
        ib_cursor = self.connection_obj.cursor() 
        so_cursor = self.connection_obj.cusror() 
        
        #.......<some logic>......

        try:
            # sql being executed using parameters in the parameter file
            ib_cursor.execute(ib_sql.read(), parameter) 
            ib_rows = ib_cursor.fetchall()
# rest of the code

def main(connection_param,parameter):
    # creating the snowflake connection
    snowflk_sql_obj = snowflk_sql(connection_param)
    # executing the sql 
    ib_df,so_df = snowflk_sql_obj.sql_execute(q_parameter)
```

But for this, I keep on getting the below error

```py
AttributeError: 'SnowflakeConnection' object has no attribute 'cusror'
```

From what I have searched, there is something about `sqlalchemy`, but what if I am just fetching the rows and then later converting to dataframe.
I am unable to understand why if it works in Jupyter, it is not working in my script too.

Comment: I think the cursor is used to fetch the dataset back from the database => however I didn't understand where your SQL query was?  I see a connection connection_obj .. you may need a result set that takes a connection and sql query then use the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a typo (cusror):

```
def sql_execute(self,parameter):
        ib_cursor = self.connection_obj.cursor() 
        so_cursor = self.connection_obj.cusror() # typo
```

Should be

```
def sql_execute(self,parameter):
        ib_cursor = self.connection_obj.cursor() 
        so_cursor = self.connection_obj.cursor() # corrected
```

Comment: I am thoroughly embarrassed and thank you so much! This is what happens when I stare at my code for a whole day.